# When is 'delete' called on temporary objects created with `new`?

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator, temporary

I initialise the SmartPtr class with `new Time(1,0,0)`.

```
    //main.cpp 
    int main()
{
    SmartPtr pTime0(new Time(0,0,1));
}
```

Nowhere am I calling delete on `new Time(1,0,0)`. Everything works fine, the program complies and runs. but I am confused -- where should/should not I `delete Time(1,0,0)` ?

I do not understand the concept of temporary objects creating and deleting here. 
I know whenever I write `new` somewhere I MUST WRITE `delete` ! 
Could someone please explain where  `delete Time(1,0,0)` takes place?

SmartPtr pTime0(new Time(0,0,1)) <-- `new` here returns a pointer to a newly allocated memory, and then in ctor I allocate `new` memory the second time??

```
//SmartPtr.cpp 

SmartPtr::SmartPtr(Pointee * p):_pointee(new Pointee(*p))
{}

SmartPtr::~SmartPtr()
{
    delete _pointee; 
}
```

Comment: Is SmartPtr a class you designed?  It could well manage object lifetime in which case the class decides when to delete.

Comment: I don't understand why you create a new Pointee on the heap in the ctor of SmartPtr. This is not what you want. You should simply write `_pointee(p)`, i.e. simply use the same pointer as given. Your statement will allocate a new Pointee and copy the contents of the provided pointer to it.

Comment: I do not want to `_pointee(p)`. if p(new Time(0,0,1)) created somewhere else outside my class, then somewhere it could be as well deleted (`delete p`), and my SmartPtr destructor will also `delete _pointee` `(initialised by p)`, so it will cause runtime error. The concept I am trying to achieve is allocating memory in ctor and deleting it in dtor.

Comment: @Oleksandra: If the code outside your class wants to delete `p` themselves, then they won't use your class.  The reason they are associating that pointer with a smart pointer class is because they expect the smart pointer to perform deallocation for them.  A possibility is for the caller to pass the content by-value and not as a pointer, then you can dynamically allocate a copy of the value (hopefully by move) which you later free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the details of your `SmartPtr` class.

In any case, if you have a constructor like this:

> ```
> SmartPtr::SmartPtr(Pointee * p):_pointee(new Pointee(*p))
> {}
> ```

and this is the destructor:

> ```
> SmartPtr::~SmartPtr()
> {
>     delete _pointee; 
> }
> ```

then with this code:

> ```
> SmartPtr pTime0(new Time(0,0,1));
> ```

you leak one instance of `Time(0,0,1)`.

In fact, you have one more `new` than `delete` (2 `new`s and 1 `delete`):

Step #1: You call `new Time(0,0,1)` and create a new object on the heap.
(`new` count == 1)

Step #2: You pass this pointer to `SmartPtr` constructor, which *deep copies* previously created object and allocates a new copy on the heap, and keeps track of this copy via its `_pointee` data member.
(`new` count == 2)

Step #3: When the `SmartPtr` destructor runs, it `delete`s the instance pointed by `_pointee` data member, but you *leaked* the firts `Time(...)` created on the heap with `new Time(0,0,1)`.
(`delete` count == 1; `new` count == 2)

A possible fix for that could be to just have this constructor:

```
SmartPtr::SmartPtr(Pointee * p)
    : _pointee(p) // <--- transfer ownerhsip (no deep copies) !
{}
```

---

An easy way to identify potential leaks in these cases is to put some console tracing output in `Time` class constructors and destructor, and check that the trace output of destructor matches the ones of constructors, e.g.:

```
Time::Time(....)
{
    // Do construction work....

    std::cout << "Time constructor\n";
}

Time::~Time(....)
{
    // Do destructor work....

    std::cout << "Time destructor\n";
}
```

The total count of `"Time constructor"` strings should match the total count of `"Time destructor"` strings.

Comment: //main.cpp    
SmartPtr ptTime(new Time(0,0,1)); gives the following: 

Time ctor(0,0,1)
SmartPtr ctor 
SmartPtr dtor
Time dtor(0,0,1).   Why the program does not abort??if it is memory leak

Comment: For logging, don't forget copy constructor too.

Comment: the number of ctors (no matter copy or default or whatever) should match the number of destructors? if so, indeed I have Time ctor, Time copy ctor, SmartPtr ctor, SmartPtr dtor, and only 1 Time destructor !!

Comment: @Oleksandra: Memory leaks usually won't abort your program, they'll just make your computer run slower than necessary, and slower, and sl.o.w.e...r.....

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to fix:

Method A, caller allocates, SmartPtr takes ownership:

```
SmartPtr::SmartPtr(Pointee * p):_pointee(p)
{
}
```

Method B, caller provides content and SmartPtr allocates:

```
SmartPtr::SmartPtr(Pointee v):_pointee(new Pointee(std::move(v)))
{
}
```

And the destructor remains the same:

```
SmartPtr::~SmartPtr()
{
    delete _pointee; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `new Time(0,0,1)` create a temporary pointer to a permanent object on the heap. The temporary pointer will indeed be destroyed automatically (which is a no-op), leaving the object still on the heap but unreferenced. A leak has occurred.

To prevent the leak, make sure to store the pointer somewhere and ensure that delete is eventually called on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your applications according to the principle **never type new**. 
Combine this with existing smart-pointers, and it becomes:

```
#include <memory>    // this is where the smart-pointers live
#include "Time.h"    // or whatever header defines your "Time" class

int main()
{
    // note that make_shared is essentially a forwarding constructor,
    // give it whatever parameters Time's constructor would take
    auto p = std::make_shared<Time>(0,0,1); 
    // use p here
}
```

And there will be no leak of anything ever.

"Never type new" should apply to all application programming,
with the only exception if you have to write a low level
resource management library.

Note that if a class does resource management, it should be it's
sole function.

All your other classes should follow [rule of zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/)